# Accessing to private classes on Java class

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose i have a class A:

```
class A
{
   private String value;
   private B field;
   public C otherField;
}

class C
{
   private String otherValue;
}

class B
{
   private String name;
}
```

Now, if i do a A.class.getClasses(), ill get an array with one element (the one which is public, something that makes sense based on what javadoc of Class.java says).

My question is: is there a way to get return a list of public + private fields of a class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getClasses()` method is not the correct way to access the *Fields* that are part of the `A` class.  You need to use the `getDeclaredFields()` method to access an array of `Field` objects representing the fields in the class.  From there, you'll need to set the accessibility of the field to `true` with a call to `setAccessible()`.  There is more information available by looking into the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) as well as [here](http://forgetfulprogrammer.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/java-reflection-class-getfields-and-class-getdeclaredfields/)

Comment: Thank you. Going to give it a try now.

Answer (score 0):

You should notice, that getDeclaredField will only return the fields of the class which are declared in the class. Fields which are inherited from a super class will not be returned. To get all fields of a class you have to iterate over the super classes (using Class.getSuperclass()).